# Restarting Supervisor and effect on FlaskSocketIO

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-socketio

In my `index.html (HTML/Javascript)` I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        namespace = '/test'; 

        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);

        socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.emit('join', {room: 'venue_1'}); 
        });       


        socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
            $('#log').append('<br>Received #' + ': ' + msg.data);
        });       
    });
```

On my `Server` I have:

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    if session.get('venue_id'):
        emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected'})      
        session.pop('venue_id', None)
    else:
        request.namespace.disconnect() 

@socketio.on('join', namespace='/test')
def join(message):
    join_room(message['room'])
    room = message['room']  
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Entered the room ' + message['room']})
```

After logging in, I set `session['venue_id'] = True` and move to `index.html`. The output I get is:

```
Received #: Connected
Received #: Entered the room venue_1
```

**My question:** After the initial run, I keep the `index.html` page open and then `stop` and `start` my project through `supervisor`. At this point why do I get the same output as above? I would have thought that after the `initial connect`, `venue_id` would have been removed from the `session` and hence `request.namespace.disconnect()` would be called?

Could someone please explain to me the sequence of events here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Socket.IO client has a reconnect logic built in. If the server goes away there is the expected disconnect, but right away the client starts to connect again, and obviously succeeds very quickly since the restart has a very short down time.